# Adding Multipart feature into Jersey Web Service in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a Jax-RS(Jersey) which has a /upload end-point where user can upload images using Multipart. Project already has other parts implemented and working correctly, the problem occurs when I try to add Multipart feature.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and Tomcat 8.5.xx to deploy my app.

My dependencies in pom.xml as follows;

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version> <!-- 2.10.1 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.42</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is my web.xml part;

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value> org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

When I launch the WAR in Tomcat, it shows Internal Server Error 500 and in logs;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:387)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
```

I don't know what is the reason for the problem. From the name of the exception, I guess it is related with the MultipartFeature that is added by the web.xml. Yet, as I am not experienced enough and my searchs on google not resulted good, I need assistance from more experienced person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, such error generally come when there are more than one mapping to `jersey` resource method for that particular URL.

You mentioned in the question that you are adding path for upload web service `/upload` . So, possible reason is this path already exist for one of your API developed before. So, check and update this path accordingly.

There are other possible reasons also for this error which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670310/why-would-java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-resource-configuration-is-not-mo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152578/learning-rest-stuck-on-illegalstateexception).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction regarding the problem